# How to use Rules in Scrapy for following some links?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to scrape a website by **Python Scrapy** and follow all the links who contain "catalogue"

I think that the smart way is using the Scrapy Rules, i try this but it doesn't follow the links

```
class Houra(CrawlSpider):
    reload(sys)
    pageNumber = 0
    name = 'houra'
    allowed_domains = ["houra.fr"]
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'catalogue/'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    ]
    def __init__(self, idcrawl=None, iddrive=None, idrobot=None, proxy=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Houra, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
def start_requests(self):
    yield Request("http://www.houra.fr", callback=self.parse_page1)
def parse_page1(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    inputElement = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#CPProspect")
    inputElement.send_keys("75001")
    inputElement.submit()

def parse_page(self, response):

    body = response.css('body').extract_first()
    f = io.open('./houra/page%s' % str(self.pageNumber), 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(body)
    f.close()
    self.pageNumber = self.pageNumber + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`restrict_xpaths` defines a region or regions where to look for the links. But you need to use `allow` instead which would check the link `href` values:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'catalogue/'), callback='parse_page', follow=True)
```

Comment: i used your code but it does'nt follow either, maybe i didn't undrestand your answer correctly

Comment: @parik then, it could be a different problem. Check that you actually have links having `catalogue/` substring inside `href` values.

Comment: Yes i have a lot of links who contain 'catalogue' in their href

Comment: @parik okay, can you post the complete code of your spider? Thanks.

Comment: @parik yeah, I remember, I'll take a look later when I have time. Thanks.

Comment: You can use allow=[r'.*',] too

Comment: @user5732284 not sure how the selenium part works in your case, but here is a sample spider (based on yours) that actually follows the catalogue links: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/1d99b6c22e6cb051b422e203d75b02d5.

Comment: @alecxe i tried what you put in github, but it doesn't work